# Map of sets into list of all combinations

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I'm stuck with a simple task. What I want to do is to transform `Map<K,Set<V>>` into the `List<Map<K,V>>` getting all possible combinations:

```
Map {
  {'k1' => set{'v11', 'v12'}},
  {'k2' => set{'v21', 'v22', 'v23'}},
  {'k3' => set{'v31'}}
}
```

Expected result:

```
List
{
  Map{'k1'=>'v11', 'k2'=>'v21', 'k3'=>'v31'}, 
  Map{'k1'=>'v11', 'k2'=>'v22', 'k3'=>'v31'},  
  Map{'k1'=>'v11', 'k2'=>'v23', 'k3'=>'v31'}, 
  Map{'k1'=>'v12', 'k2'=>'v21', 'k3'=>'v31'}, 
  Map{'k1'=>'v12', 'k2'=>'v22', 'k3'=>'v31'}, 
  Map{'k1'=>'v12', 'k2'=>'v23', 'k3'=>'v31'}
}
```

Comment: What will be the key and value in new Map?

Comment: @maks, thanks for your interest, both are arbitrary objects if it does matter.

Comment: Are there exactly two entries in the input map?  As I read it, your description would suggest that you also would expect entries in the example result of the form map{'k2'=>*, 'k1'=>*} - especially if there can be more than two input entries.  If not, please explain which combinations should be there and which not.  Perhaps the output, semantically, is really just a list of unordered pairs or a bidirectional map - not really a normal unidirectional map?  That would explain it.  (Also, removing my answer- it assumed homework.)

Comment: @Ed Staub, yes, question presumes arbitrary number of keys with variable number of values for each key. The output list size is a power of sizes of corresponding arg set sizes, in my case it's 2*3=6. If I had the third key named `k3` with 4 set entries, then the output list size would be 2*3*4=24. As for your answer - let's forget it, and i'm sorry for my pretty rough comment on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use recursion! So at each level of the recursion, you look at another key in the `keyset()` of the map. You add iteratively add elements in the `Set<V>` for that key to the current map that you want to add to the list.

You can think of this as a tree. At the root node, you have an empty list. Then each subsequent level of the tree `i` represents a choice of which element to take from the `i`th set.

Here is the code along with a main method containing a test case:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    // method called to generate combinations using map, putting the combinations in list
    public static <K,V> void combinations( Map<K,Set<V>> map, List<Map<K,V>> list ) {
        recurse( map, new LinkedList<K>( map.keySet() ).listIterator(), new HashMap<K,V>(), list );
    }

    // helper method to do the recursion
    private static <K,V> void recurse( Map<K,Set<V>> map, ListIterator<K> iter, Map<K,V> cur, List<Map<K,V>> list ) {
            // we're at a leaf node in the recursion tree, add solution to list
        if( !iter.hasNext() ) {
            Map<K,V> entry = new HashMap<K,V>();

            for( K key : cur.keySet() ) {
                entry.put( key, cur.get( key ) );
            }

            list.add( entry );
        } else {
            K key = iter.next();
            Set<V> set = map.get( key );

            for( V value : set ) {
                cur.put( key, value );
                recurse( map, iter, cur, list );
                cur.remove( key );
            }

            iter.previous();
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Map<Integer,Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer,Set<Integer>>() {{
            put( 1, new HashSet<Integer>() {{
                add( 11 );
                add( 12 );
            }} );
            put( 2, new HashSet<Integer>() {{
                add( 21 );
                add( 22 );
                add( 23 );
            }} );
            put( 3, new HashSet<Integer>() {{
                add( 31 );
            }} );
        }};
        List<Map<Integer,Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Map<Integer,Integer>>();
        combinations( map, list );

        for( Map<Integer,Integer> combination : list ) {
            System.out.println( combination );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I adapted it slightly to fit my needs (I have `Map<K1,Map<K2,V>>`) and it works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use recursion to generate a combination "tree".

**Edit**: Ok, I had some free time and decided to give it shot:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param <K> The type of the key
 * @param <V> The type of the value
 * @param index The index of the current key to inspect
 * @param current The current map being built by recursion
 * @param map The original input
 * @param list The result
 */ 
public static <K, V> void Combine(int index, Map<K, V> current, 
                                  Map<K, Set<V>> map, 
                                  List<Map<K, V>> list) {
    
    if(index == map.size()) { // if we have gone through all keys in the map
        Map<K, V> newMap = new HashMap<K, V>();
        System.out.println(current);
        for(K key: current.keySet()) {          // copy contents to new map.    
            newMap.put(key, current.get((K)key));               
        }           
        list.add(newMap); // add to result.
    } else {
        Object currentKey = map.keySet().toArray()[index]; // take the current key
        for(V value: map.get(currentKey)) {
            current.put((K)currentKey, value); // put each value into the temporary map
            Combine(index + 1, current, map, list); // recursive call
            current.remove(currentKey); // discard and try a new value
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested on a few cases and I think it's correct. Let me know.
You can call this from another method that only takes `map` as input, creates the default parameters `index`, `current` and `list` and returns `list` as output.

**Edit** Small Java 8+ Update

```
public static <K, V> void combine(int index, Map<K, V> current, Map<K, List<V>> map, List<Map<K, V>> list) {

    if (index == map.size()) { // if we have gone through all keys in the map
        System.out.println(current);
        list.add(new HashMap<>(current)); // add to result.
    } else {
        K currentKey = map.keySet().stream().skip(index).findFirst().get(); // take the current key
        for (V value : map.get(currentKey)) {
            current.put(currentKey, value); // put each value into the temporary map
            combine(index + 1, current, map, list); // recursive call
            current.remove(currentKey); // discard and try next value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I know recursion will save me, but I just cant see it. that's the problem.

Comment: works excellent, thanks! Putting it to work immediately as `TudorOnStackoverflow.java` :) My all-rep bounty proposal is still valid, your and Ed's responsiveness will be rewarded.

Comment: Bounty or no bounty, I was glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

**VERY** updated.

Here's a solution for [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)-heads.  It should be pretty easy to convert if Guava's not your thing.  This one is not recursive.  It outputs a list of pairs of string-pairs, which I think is what you really want.

```
static ImmutableMap<String,ImmutableSet<String>> input = ImmutableMap.of(
    "k1", ImmutableSet.of("v11", "v12"),
    "k2", ImmutableSet.of("v21", "v22", "v23"),
    "k3", ImmutableSet.of("v31", "v32", "v33", "v34"));

static class Pair<T,U>
{
    T left;        U right;
    static <T,U> Pair of(T l, U r)
    {   return new Pair(l, r);      }
    Pair(T l, U r)    { left = l; right = r; }
}

static List<Pair<Pair<String, String>,Pair<String, String>>> transform(Map<String,ImmutableSet<String>> input)
{
    List<Pair<Pair<String, String>,Pair<String, String>>> output = Lists.newArrayList();
    // Not a real copy - very cheap.
    ImmutableList<Map.Entry<String, ImmutableSet<String>>> entryList = ImmutableList.copyOf(input.entrySet());
    for ( int i = 0; i < entryList.size(); i++ )
    {
        final Map.Entry<String, ? extends Set<String>> leftEntry = entryList.get(i);
        for ( int j = i+1; j < entryList.size(); j++ )
        {
            final Map.Entry<String, ? extends Set<String>> rightEntry = entryList.get(j);
            for ( String v1 : leftEntry.getValue() )
                for ( String v2 : rightEntry.getValue() )
                    output.add(Pair.of(
                        Pair.of(leftEntry.getKey(), v1),
                        Pair.of(rightEntry.getKey(), v2)));
        }

    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: I can also speak german. See update to the question, you might be interested.

Comment: @Osw - ah, so - but can you speak Guava ;-)?  See above.

Comment: You've just managed to make me mad at myself twice! First for not being able to solve the subj, and second - for not understanding your answer :) Pair of Pairs drives me especially crazy. Are there any chances that your approach is able to return list of map? Then I'd split the reward between you two and implement random execution of your and Tudor's solutions :)

Comment: Look at your output - each entry is an ordered pair of ordered pairs, isn't it?  Making zillions of maps with only one entry in each one doesn't make sense to me - sorry.  I don't know the real-world meanings for the entries, so I couldn't make up Pair classes with names that make sense.  For the outer pairs, you can just make a simple subclass of Pair if that's are confusing.  I'd either use a class as I did, or just arrays, which for me tend to be less clear.

Comment: hmm, my output seems to be pair of pairs just because I used only two keys in my example. Generally speaking in your terms the output is a list of pairs: `{k1->v11, k2-v22, k3->v32, ...}` Your code produces correct combinations, I'll play with it a bit more, but at this moment of time i cant understand the reason for pair of pairs here :(

Comment: @Osw, We're not communicating, despite trying hard!  I see the entry in your example `map{'k1'=>'v12', 'k2'=>'v23' }` as a pair of pairs: [[k1,v12],[k2,v23]].  The two inner pairs are related in your output by being in a map together - yes?  They couldn't just be two separate entries without losing information.

Comment: I think what Osw is saying is whether your program can produce an arbitrary number of key-value pairs for each entry of the output, or just a pair of pairs?

Comment: @Tudor - It's just a pair of pairs for each entry in the _output_.  I think this is consistent with `The output list size is a power of sizes of corresponding arg set sizes, in my case it's 2*3=6. If I had the third key named k3 with 4 set entries, then the output list size would be 2*3*4=24.`  That's what this code outputs.

Comment: I don't know, but from my testing and given the type of transform's output I deduced that you are producing list of pairs of key->value, not all possible combinations of N key-value pairs, as requested in the question. In the question example, the output should produce 2 x 3 x 1 = 6 combinations each with 3 pairs, while your code produces 11 pairs.

Comment: @Tudor - agreed, with today's example.

Comment: @Ed Staub, just wanted that you haven't missed my last update. No matter how we've been communicating, many thanks for being close when it's been hard.

Answer (score 0):

First thank you for the case and the provided implementations! We got across the same issue, and saved us a ton of time to see them! We leave a python implementation, for those who may deal with the same issue but in another language :)

```
def combinations(themap, maplist):
    return recurse(themap, themap.keys(), {}, maplist, 0)

def recurse(themap, iterator, curmap, maplist, iteratoridx):
    if(iteratoridx>=len(iterator)):
        entry = {}
        for key in curmap.keys():
            entry[key]=curmap[key]
        maplist.append(entry)
    else:
        key = iterator[iteratoridx]
        theset = themap.get(key)
        for value in theset:
            curmap[key]=value
            recurse(themap, iterator, curmap, maplist, iteratoridx+1)
            curmap.pop(key, None)
        iteratoridx=iteratoridx-1


maplist=[]
grid={"A":[1, 2, 3], "B":[4, 5, 6], "C":[7, 8, 9]}
combinations(grid, maplist)
print(maplist)
```

Answer (score -1):

suppose we have the variable "source" from the type `Map<K,Set<V>>` to transform source to the required type you can use the next code:

```
List<Map<K,V>> target = new ArrayList<Map<K,V>>();
for(K key : source.keySet()){
    Map<K,V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();
    for(V val : source.get(key)){
       map.put(key, val)
    }
    target.add(map);
}
```

Comment: You will not produce the desired result. At each iteration of the outer loop you are producing a map with the current key and its associated values.

Answer (score -1):

```
List<Map<K,V>> target = new ArrayList<Map<K,V>>();
for(K key : source.keySet()){
    for(V val : source.get(key)){
       Map<K,V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();
       map.put(key, val)
       target.add(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just took another look at the expected output and now I see that this is not what OP is looking for.